# Get string between <BR> and : without <BR> inside the substring

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I'm trying to create a Regular Expression on iOS to get a substring between `<BR>` and `:`.

I have tried this, but it won't work:

```
<BR>[A-Z](.*[^<BR>]):
```

This is an example of an text where I only want to get the `THE TEXT I WANT`

`TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST<BR>THE TEXT I WANT:more text <BR>TEST TEST TEST TESTTEST TESTTEST TEST<BR>TEST TESTTEST TESTTEST TESTTEST TEST<BR>THE TEXT I WANT:TEST TESTTEST TESTTEST TESTTEST TEST`

My regular expression seems to get text after the first `:` and stop after the second `:` which I'm not interested in.

I want the `THE TEXT I WANT` both times it occurs and nothing else.

How can I do this?

Comment: Whenever you can, use a html parser (such as the one included with libxml2) to parse HTML, not a regex. There are simply too many problems with HTML in the wild that regexes cannot deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any experience with Objective-C, so I can't really give advice on the implementation. This regex works for the sample text you provided. Use it with the case insensitive option. The text between the BR and the colon is found inside capture group 1.

```
<BR\s*/?\s*>([\w\s]+):
```

It will only allow letters, number, underscores and white-space characters to be between the BR tag and the colon.

You can of course add other characters in the character class, but if you add all the characters that allow you to build a tag, it will no longer work correctly.

If your regex engine supports negative lookaheads, you could use this next regex instead. Use it with the case insensitive option.

The text between the BR and the colon is found inside capture group 1.

```
<BR\s*/?\s*>(?![^:]+<BR\s*/?\s*>)([^:]+):
```

Here is a rough breakdown of this last regex:

```
<BR\s*/?\s*>            #Match the starting BR tag.
(?![^:]+<BR\s*/?\s*>)   #Make sure that there are no BR tags between this BR tag and the next colon character.
([^:]+):                #GROUP 1: Match every character up to the next colon character.
```

Comment: For future reference - iOS's regex library (NSRegularExpression) does in fact support negative lookaheads.

Comment: Thank you! `<BR\s*/?\s*>(?![^:]+<BR\s*/?\s*>)([^:]+):` works perfectly! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *pieces = [inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@"<BR>"];
NSInteger numberOfPieces = [pieces count];
for (NSInteger i = 1; i < numberOfPieces; i++) {
    NSArray *subpieces = [[pieces objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    if ([subpieces count] > 1) {
        // [subpieces objectAtIndex:0] is the string you're interested in
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't very flexible. It won't match lowercase `br`s, and it simply won't work for properly formed HTML (such as `<br/>`).

Comment: I guess it's likely that OP is trying to parse HTML, but from the example string he gave, this naive approach would work fine. If that's not actually the input he's starting with then another solution might be more appropriate.